# Converter CSV para xlsx, em vba

Tags: vba

Estou a utilizar este código para converter de CSV para XLSX. Mas está ignorando o `OtherChar:=";"` e separando as colunas na vírgula.

```
Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
 Dim xlBook As Object 'Excel.Workbook
 Dim xlSht As Object 'Excel.Worksheet

 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

 '################### teste de conversão de tipo de ficheiro cvs to xlsx







 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  objExcel.Visible = False
  objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.text)
Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook.Worksheets("E60POR03")
objWorksheet1.Columns("$A:$A").TextToColumns destination:=objWorksheet1.Range("A1"), dataType:=1, _
        TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=";", _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), _
            Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1) _
            , Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array( _
            19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1)), _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


        'FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(36, 1)), _

'Save Spreadsheet, 51 = Excel 2007-2010
 objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Left(TextBox1.text, InStrRev(TextBox1.text, ".") - 1), FileFormat:=51

' objExcel.Workbooks.Close
 objExcel.Quit

 Set objExcel = Nothing
 Set objWorkbook = Nothing
 Set objWorksheet1 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

A resposta está no seu próprio código. Repare na seguinte linha onde você instrui o que o Excel tem que considerar e desconsiderar:

```
TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=";",
```

Você está dizendo para ele ignorar o ponto e vírgula no atributo `Semicolon` com o `False` e dizendo para ele usar a vírgula no atributo `Comma` setado em `True`. Basta alterar isto e remover os campos `Other` e `OtherChar`.

Fica assim:

```
Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Object 'Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSht As Object 'Excel.Worksheet

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'################### teste de conversão de tipo de ficheiro cvs to xlsx

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.text)
Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook.Worksheets("E60POR03")
objWorksheet1.Columns("$A:$A").TextToColumns destination:=objWorksheet1.Range("A1"), dataType:=1, _
TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), _
Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1) _
, Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array( _
19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1)), _
TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'Save Spreadsheet, 51 = Excel 2007-2010
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Left(TextBox1.text, InStrRev(TextBox1.text, ".") - 1), FileFormat:=51

' objExcel.Workbooks.Close
objExcel.Quit

Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objWorksheet1 = Nothing
```